# Encapsulating a (pure Ruby) Ragel parser for infinite streams?

Tags: ruby, parsing, state-machine, ragel

I want to parse a continuous stream of bytes (from a socket) with a state machine using Ragel

However, all the Examples I have found are either parsing a complete file in one pass (like [the Gherkin lexer](http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/gherkin/blob/v0.0.4/ragel/lexer.rb.rl.erb) or are using Ragels C Target (like the [mongrel HTTP1.1 Parser](http://github.com/fauna/mongrel/blob/master/ext/http11/http11_parser.rl))

I'm looking for some advice or examples on how to instantiate a Ragel State machine and then add bytes to it, keeping the existing state intact.

The final interface I am looking for is something like:

```
parser = MyStreamParser.new(Grammar)
parser.on_token { |t| puts t.inspect }

# I can't parse lines seperately because tokens can span multiple lines.
$stdin.each_line do |line|
  parser.add(line)
end
```

Any advice on how to do that in Ragel is greatly appreciated. I'd rather use that than code  another state machine by hand.

Maybe Ragel is not the right tool? If not: What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, Ragel doesn't look very Ruby-like.  Have you taken a look at [Statemachine](http://statemachine.rubyforge.org/)?  It looks like you can feed the state machine events (characters, in your problem) one at a time.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  Statemachine rocks.  I'm replacing one of work's hand-made state engines with Statemachine right now.

Comment: Statemachine is nice for what it does, but it (I believe) does not have the features i'd like (I would afaict still need a lexer to convert my byte stream into tokens and it can't do things like lookahead, priorities, semantic conditions unless I build them myself)

Comment: Fair enough.  Sorry it wasn't helpful to you.  But thanks for asking a cool question.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly what you are looking for, but [Dhaka](http://dhaka.rubyforge.org/) is another decent parser generator to take a look at.  I'm not sure that will help, but it has served me well in the past.